# if/else in erb executing code it should not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

**Thanks** to everyone for providing me with information! There were some very quick responses. My solution was to use a clearer test in the if. Grammar for the win!

"You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! The error occurred while evaluating nil.name"

This error points to the line below with "file.name".

I get why it evaluates to nil.name and is empty(it should be) but I don't understand why that code is even executed.

It works by changing the test for if to..

```
if file[0] != nil
```

I feel like there's an important detail I'm missing so I'd appreciate some help with understanding this.

In my view I have:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>File</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>

  <% if !@files.empty? %>
    <% @files.each do |file| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= file.name %></td>
      <td><%= file.description %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Download", :controller => "files", :action => "download", :id => file.id %></td>
      <td><%= button_to "Delete", { :controller => "files", :action => "destroy", :id => file.id }, :method => "delete" %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>

  <% else %>

  <tr>
    <td><b>No files</b></td>
  </tr>

  <% end %>
</table>
```

In the controller I create an empty array called @files and then push in values later when they're created.

Ruby 1.8.7-p72
Rails 2.2.2

Comment: The trouble isn't in the view.  It's in the controller, where you are adding a nil to @files.  Can you please post the code from the controller?

Comment: also .. refer to http://apidock.com/rails/v2.2.1/Object/present%3F .. an alternative to `!@files.empty?` would be `@files.present?` this also checks for `@files` being `nil` (it's just a nicer syntax)

Comment: Simple, `@files` contains one or more `nil`s. Note that `![nil].empty?` returns `true` (not `false`) -- to be clearer, `[nil].present?` will return `true`. What you can use is `@files.compact.each`. Or better, ensure that `@files` does not contain `nil` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Matenia! I wasn't aware of the present method. That works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks.. I'm kind of new to posting here. I tried to vote the answers up but I can't until I have enough "rep".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want in your `@files` instance var is either an empty array

```
@files = []
```

or actual `File` objects

```
@files = File.all
```

but you seem to somehow produce an array that contains `nil` elements, for example

```
@files = [nil, <#File>, <#File>]
```

so @files itself is not nil, while its first element is. Therefore, the following code returns `true`

```
@files.any?
```

which is equivalent to

```
!@files.empty?
```

because `@files.is_a? Array` and `not @files.nil?`. Your problem must be in the corresponding controller, where you seem to add a `nil` element to your `@files`.

Comment: Thanks for bring the any? method up. This is another new one for me. Using !@files.empty? makes the logic too confusing. I realize now that it was executing when I thought it shouldn't because the array was empty and I put the ! on there to make it true. If I was going to use that logic I should have had ... @files.empty? == false

Comment: @johnny2k you're welcome. If this solved your problem, please do not change the title of the question to `[solved]`, but accept the answer by checking the little tick to the left. You may also consider an upvote if you like the answer. This shows other people that the answer is in fact correct. Also, the poster of the answer can gain reputation this way.

Comment: I would love to vote all of these answers up but I don't have the reputation level yet.